# Rails - "Required ruby-2.3.3 is not installed." after Ruby update to 2.5.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler

I have a Rails install where I updated the Ruby version from 2.3.3 to 2.5.3. I was previously using 2.3.3 from the Debian Ruby package, but installed 2.5.3 from RVM. I modified my Gemfile to use `ruby '2.5.3'` and ran `bundle install`. Rails is now using 2.5.3 as it should, but when I cd to the directory, I get a message:

`Required ruby-2.3.3 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-2.3.3"'`

I can't find where it's getting this. Running `grep -r "2.3.3" *` in my Rails project root returns nothing. I know it's something specific to this project, because I've cloned it over to another server and the message persists. What is reporting this and how do I tell it that 2.5.3 is the correct Ruby version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.ruby-version`

Also, if you had grepped with `grep -r "2.3.3" .` you would have found it.

Comment: That's it, thank you! `grep -r "2.3.3" *` doesn't include hidden files! That's why I couldn't find it. I should have been using `grep -r "2.3.3" .`

Comment: I copy pasted your grep and forgot to change the asterisk to dot afterwards, as I initially intended to do... :p